# running build_ext gives `[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` while building detectron2

Tags: pytorch, setuptools, detectron

I'm currently trying to build detectron2 in environment in Anaconda. Below is the packages that I'm using in my env:

- windows 11
- conda package
- python 3.8
- cuda 11.3
- pytorch 1.11
- torchaudio 0.11.0
- torchvision 0.12.0
- ninja 1.10.2
- pybind11 2.10.4

I've cloned the git to my own directory so I was installing detectron2 with this command
`python -m pip install -e detectron2`
(detectron2 is the folder name for the cloned git)
But, I received this error while building detectron2 with setup.py

```
running develop
    running egg_info
    writing detectron2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to detectron2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to detectron2.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to detectron2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'detectron2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    adding license file 'LICENSE'
    writing manifest file 'detectron2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    c:\conda\detect\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py:40: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
    !!

            ********************************************************************************
            Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
            Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer, pypa/build or
            other standards-based tools.

            See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
            ********************************************************************************

    !!
      easy_install.initialize_options(self)
    c:\conda\detect\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
    !!

            ********************************************************************************
            Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
            Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer, pypa/build or
            other standards-based tools.

            See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
            ********************************************************************************

    !!
      self.initialize_options()
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've tried other method such as running:
`python -m pip install .`
while being in the cloned git path, but I kept getting the same error, which is The system cannot find the file specified while running build_ext.
Running
`python setup.py build develop`
also gave me the same error, which says:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I realized that this might be a problem with setuptools package. I've tried to update the package, downgrade my python to 3.7, downgrade my pytorch to 1.10, and add C++ compiler to my device Path, but the problem stays the same.
Me and my mentor currently are running out of ideas. Perhaps anyone has any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem. I had installed torch and its corresponding cuda from conda but didn't have any local cuda installs from Nvidia.

I solved this by making sure I have the correct cudatoolkit manually installed from the Nvidia website and have the CUDA_PATH and CUDA_HOME environment variables pointed to its directory. The cuda runtime and cudatoolkit that are installed using conda are apparently bare-bone and don't satisfy the requirements when installing cuda-dependant packages such as detectron2 and mmcv.